# mysqli_fetch_array not working properly PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I've been told that I was using an deprecated version of PHP, mysql_query, instead of the newer version mysqli_query, and soon it will be remove. Knowing that, I quickly tried to update all of my old, deprecated codes into the newer code. Doing that, I quickly ran into a problem, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please take a look:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect('server','username','password','database');
$fetch = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT username FROM userLogin");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch,MYSQLI_NUM)){

//do something

}

?>
```

output:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/a2056400/public_html/test4.php on line 8
```

I have a feeling the error message has something to do with the conditional statement inside the while loop, but I'm not sure what is wrong with it. Please help in any way. Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the error message? It seems to me that it clearly refers to the 2nd parameter that's being passed to `mysqli_fetch_array()`. In your code, the 2nd parameter is `mysqli_NUM` when you probably mean to use the constant `MYSQLI_NUM `.

Comment: @CharlieS I'm sorry. In the older version, you're suppose to use mysql_NUM as oppose to MYSQL_NUM, so when I switched over, I thought the same rule applies. I guess I know that it doesn't now. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not connecting to the database properly.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('server','username','password','database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$fetch = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT username FROM userLogin");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch,MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    //do something

}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.